# trying to learn to use it with SQL Server CE

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-ce

I was able to add an `sqlDataSource` and make it work in the Design view but I would like to do it in the code but that's where I can't seem to make it work.

I have Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0 installed on my pc. I think there's an error in my Connection String but that's just my opinion, it looks something like this :

```
"Data Source=\"C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Databases\\Database.sdf\";Password=MyPassword;Persist Security Info=True"
```

But honestly if even I get the connection string right, I'm kind of in the dark on where to go after that, so if you would have any tips or even good tutorials on that, it would help a bunch.
If the problem isn't my ConnectionString then it must be somewhere else or I'm just not doing it right so here's the rest of my code :

```
sqlDataSourceDB.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM quote";
DataView dv = (DataView)sqlDataSourceDB.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
String resultat = (String)dv.Table.Rows[0][0];
```

The two last lines were taken from an msdn mini walkthrough

Une erreur liée au réseau ou spécifique à l'instance s'est produite lors de l'établissement d'une connexion à SQL Server. Le serveur est introuvable ou n'est pas accessible. Vérifiez que le nom de l'instance est correct et que SQL Server est configuré pour autoriser les connexions distantes. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Erreur lors de la localisation du serveur/de l'instance spécifiés)
The error looks like that (it is translated from french) :

```
An error liked to the network or the instance happened when establishing a connection to     SQL Server. 
The server is not found or cannot be accessed. 
Check that the instance name is correct and that the SQL Server is correctly configured to allow distant connection. 
(provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error 26 - Error when locating the server/instance)
```

RESOLVED : Alright, I realized that in Design View when I added the SqlDataSource it was working but not when I was coding it so I checked the full  line and just saw my own stupidity; I had to specify the ProviderName -.- everything worked after that. Story lesson here, always overcheck everything instead of making stupid post. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Why do you think you have an error in your connection string? Is there something that indicates this? PS: resource requests (like a tutorial) are offtopic here and will only result in your question being put on hold. Refer to the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for more information.

Comment: Oops okay sorry about that. When I launch the page it tells me there's an exception that was thrown where I use the sqlDataSource.Select and it tells me there's an error linked to the SQL connection so I'm only guessing at that point. I might as well add the rest of my code because if it's not my connection string then my question makes no sense.

Comment: Can you copy paste the exact error message and put it in your post?

Comment: I just edited my post adding some elements

Answer (score 0):

You add in your connection string to the config file which is included with every new project in visual studio like so:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="main" connectionString="Data Source=\"C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Databases\\Database.sdf\";Password=MyPassword;Persist Security Info=True" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

The tutorial below makes use of something slightly different so it's up to you how you implement depending on your environment.

And your code behind file: (You will need to import SqlServerCe namespace)

```
string sql = "select * from blah";
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sql, ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["main"].ConnectionString);
SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

foreach(DataRow r in dt.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r["something"].ToString());
}
```

Full tutorial on Sql Compact Edition at dotnetperls: http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlce. The tutorial uses a reader to print the data out to the console, but you can just fill a DataTable like I have above quite as easily.